# Why is the ajax request not executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request

Explain what is wrong here. First, the `run` function and its `ajax` request must be executed. But for some reason the function is executed, and the `ajax` request is not. It runs right at the very end of the script - after all the functions ... Why is this happening and how to fix it?..

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="id_product_create_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>

<div class="media_preview_wrap">
  <div class="addPhoto">
    <div class="addPhotoHeader">
      <button type="button" class="button product_images_button">Add</button>
      <button id="id_submit" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="file" name="image" style="display: none" required="" class="product_images" id="">

<script>
var files = [];

  $('.product_images_button').click(function() {
    $('.product_images').click();
  });

  $('.product_images').change(function() {
    handleFiles(this);
  });

  $('.media_preview_wrap').on('click', '.thumb', function() {
    removeFile($(this).data('id'));
  });

  $('#id_submit').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

     var $form = $('form'),
         formdata = new FormData($form[0]),
         $button = $('#id_submit');
     formdata.append('content', CKEDITOR.instances.id_content.getData());
     function run() {
       var product_id = null;
     $.ajax($form.attr('action'),{
       type: 'POST',
       data: formdata,
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       success: function(data) {
         product_id = data.product_id;
       }, error: function(error) {
          console.log(error)
      }
    });
     return product_id}
     product_id = run();
    files.forEach(function(file, index) {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('name', file.name);
      data.append('gallery_image', file.file);
      uploadFile(event.target.action, data)
        .done(function(response) {
          removeFile(file.id);
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  });


  function handleFiles(input) {
    var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

    var uniqueId = (new Date()).getTime()
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {
      var file = input.files[i];

      if (file && file.type.startsWith('image/')) {
        uniqueId++;

        files.push({
          id: uniqueId,
          file: file,
          name: file.name // задел для возможности переименования файла.
        });

        var img = $('<img src="'+ URL.createObjectURL(file) +'" class="thumb" data-id="'+ uniqueId +'">');
        $('.media_preview_wrap').append(img);

        img.on('load', function() {
          URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        });
      }
    }

    $(input).val('');
  }

  function removeFile(id) {
    files = files.filter(function(file) {
      return id !== file.id;
    })

    $('img[data-id="'+ id +'"]').remove();
  }

  function uploadFile(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
      headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false
     });
  }
</script>

<style>
    .thumb {
      width: 150px;
      height: auto;
      opacity: 0.9;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .thumb:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    .product_images {
      display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial problem is likely due to  some browsers having a global `event` object while  others don't.

You are likely getting an error that `event` is undefined and that would prevent the remaining code to run

Use the argument of the event handler function which always passes in an event object:

```
$('#id_submit').click(function(event) {
                              // ^^^
    event.preventDefault();
```

Once that issue is solved... you need to realize that `$.ajax` is asynchronous and you can't use the new value of `product_id` until first request completes in the `success` callback

See [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thnx. I'm used _Side note: jQuery's deferred objects_